# Variable always returning true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this in my button click event:

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    authentication auth = new authentication();

    bool emailExists = auth.checkEmail(System.Convert.ToString(txt_email.Text));

    if (emailExists == true)
    {
        btn_create.Text = "Email doesnt exist";
    }
    else
    {
        btn_create.Text = "Email exists";
    }

}
```

It sends the email to my checkEmail method which is in my authentication class:

```
public bool checkEmail(string email)
{
    bool emailExists = false;

    usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();

    users.UsersDataTable userDataTable = user.checkEmail(email);

    if (userDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        emailExists = false;
    }
    else
    {
        emailExists = true;
    }

    return emailExists;

}
```

The checkEmail query is "SELECT COUNT(email) AS email FROM People WHERE (email = ?)"

However when I debug, it always falls through the if(emailExists == true) statement even when the email already exists in my DB, does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you manually tried your query if what's the value it returned?

Answer (score 3):

your query you entered will always have 1 result. If you want to continue using that query, you should check the first column ("email") of the first result and check to see if that is == 0 or not.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your answer. Are you trying to say check the column email?

Comment: yes, the result of your query will always contain 1 result row with 1 result column.  That will have a value of 0 or more which represent instances of people that match your email you passed in.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh I understand, so how would I check the value?

Answer (score 0):

can't add code markup in comments, so reposting how I would rewrite the checkEmail method: (assuming the how the UsersTableAdapter type is setup)

```
public bool checkEmail(string email)
{
    usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();

    users.UsersDataTable userDataTable = user.checkEmail(email);

    return userDataTable.Rows[0][0] > 0;

}
```

Comment: Then, i would want to know what type .Rows[0] would return, if it doesn't have a default property on it like most datatables i'm familiar with i'd look to see how you could pull out a value when specifying the first column in the resultset.

Comment: I've answered myself, just figured it out. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I would have to check the index of the row which in this case is 0 and then retrieve and store the value from the email column into an int

```
DataRow row = userDataTable.Rows[0];
int rowValue = System.Convert.ToInt16(row["email"]);
```